# Transform XML containing a dictionary using Groovy

Tags: xml, xslt, dictionary, groovy

I have a XML file containing a dictionary like the example below. I'm trying to convert this XML in Groovy so that the linked id's are filled in with the actual values.

```
<root>
    <dictionary>
        <list_car>
            <car_name>Ferrari</car_name>
            <car_color>red</car_color>
            <specs_id>0</specs_id>
        </list_car>
        <list_car>
            <car_name>Porsche</car_name>
            <car_color>black</car_color>
            <specs_id>0</specs_id>
        </list_car>
        <list_specs>
            <pk>570</pk>
            <engine>4,5 l</engine>
        </list_specs>
    </dictionary>
    <persons>
        <person>
            <name>James</name>
            <car_id>0</car_id>
        </person>
        <person>
             <name>John</name>
             <car_id>1</car_id>
        </person>
    </persons>
</root>
```

What is the fastest way for transforming the whole XML, so that the < car_id > & < specs_id  > elements are replaced with the actual elements. Somehting like below:

```
<person>
    <name>John</name>
    <car>
        <car_name>Porsche</car_name>
        <car_color>black</car_color>
        <specs>        
            <pk>570</pk>
            <engine>4,5 l</engine>
        </specs>
    </car>
</person>
```

My original XML is pretty complex and a bit bigger (1MB).
I was thinking about using XSLT, but my knowledge about it is not that great so a other suggestions would be great. I also worked with XmlSlurper, but I think this is too slow in my case.

EDIT:

I used XmlParser because it is faster then XmlSlurper.

First I loop over the LIST_CAR elements and give them an id according to the position (ID=1, ID=2, ID=3, ...) This is a more proper way then linking the ID's to the position of the dictionary element.

```
<list_car car_id="0">
        <car_name>Ferrari</car_name>
        <car_color>red</car_color>
        <specs_id>0</specs_id>
    </list_car>
```

Then I loop over the PERSON elements, remove the CAR_ID element with node.Remove(...)
After that I add the actual data from the LIST_CAR in person by making a inner loop with the LIST_CAR dictionary elements

```
root.persons.each { person ->

    def carId = person.car_id.text()

    def nodeToDel= person.car_id.find{ it.name() == "car_id" }

    root.dictionary.list_car.findAll{ it.@car_id == carId.toInteger() }.each { s ->

        def parent = nodeToDel.parent()
        parent.remove(nodeToDel)
        parent.appendNode('CAR',s.value())
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the relation between your starting and ending XML. Can you update your question to explain that better? Why is the Porshe car_id 1?

Comment: I think part of the confusion comes from the fact that XPath uses 1-based index and not 0. So naturally an ID of 1 would be the first car not the second one. If that is the case, it can be worked around in the XSLT but if you are able it would be better to match your ID's with that construct.